# PHP shell_exec(), exec(), system(), passthru() how to make them work for all commands?

Tags: php, linux, linux-mint

Some commands that I run using `shell_exec`, `exec`, `system`, `passthru` does not work when I run the .php file inside the browsers.

Actually if I execute shell commands/progs there are no problems but if I try to run some progs it doesn't work:

```
system("sleep 5 && fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 100 -D 5 -S 12 fswebcam.jpg");

shell_exec("sleep 5 && fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 100 -D 5 -S 12 fswebcam.jpg");

exec("sleep 5 && fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 100 -D 5 -S 12 fswebcam.jpg");

passthru("sleep 5 && fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 100 -D 5 -S 12 fswebcam.jpg");
```

The `sleep` command works but the fswebcam doesn't. If I try, for example, with mplayer it runs too. Why?

Comment: You should probably put the sleep in your PHP.  And include the *full and complete path* to whereever the `fswebcam` binary lives... and the full and complete path to where you want the captured image to live.  Also, look up [`proc_open`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), which will let you capture stderr, which may contain the error messages you're possibly missing...

Comment: Plus does the user executing the commands in PHP have the permissions necessary to do so?

Comment: Ooh, good one @Jacob.  Mint is based on Ubuntu, so it's probably using [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor), a security restriction layer that might be *correctly* preventing the binary from being called *or* might be preventing it from working correctly.  You may need to check the server logs.

Comment: You can capture stderr with system/shell_exec/exec/passthru as well, just use &2>1 - use that to get error messages about what's wrong.

Comment: Probably `fswebcam` command not found or some errors, use &2>1.

Comment: Thanks. Actually is 2&>1. At least that worked for me.

Comment: I've changed the folder's owner and add the www-data to the video group.